# How to select specific css in pug file with 'include' basing on route

Tags: css, node.js, pug

I want to make dynamic page, which will chosoe which css it have to apply, basing on route.js file. I am coding this page in node.js and pug. I have tried similar methods to this one.

**routes.js file**

```
router.get("/", (req,res) => {
const indexCss = "rel='stylesheet' href='index.css' "
res.render("index"), {css:indexCss};
});
```

**index.pug file**

```
head
    link(#{css})
    title Index Page
```

Unfortunately it did not work. 
I was wondering about selecting **link** with req and body-parser but I think it does not work that way either.

I think it would be really useful, It would make possibility to make head partial and just include it with specified css in routes.js file to make code more organised and shorter.

I don`t have any more ideas tho. Can someone point me out how can I do it, or give any idea I can mess with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pug doesn't handle attribute interpolation like that. If you want to pass a variable containing a stylesheet path from the router to Pug, you could do it like this:

**routes.js**

```
router.get('/', (req,res) => {
  const cssPath = 'index.css'
  res.render('index', { cssPath })
})
```

**index.pug**

```
head
  link(rel='stylesheet', href= cssPath)
  title Index Page
```

More info on [Pug attribute interpolation in the Pug documentation](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#attribute-interpolation).

Comment: Oh, thank you - it works. Imma definitely take a look on documentation either.